Help identifying SMD diode
I'm retrofitting an 8BitDo Pro 2 controller for a project, and in doing so I melted one of the components on the board. I'm looking into ordering another one, as it was the same as another component on the board. However, this component doesn't have very much identification. It has a 'C' on it, as well as a line. I believe it is some sort of diode. I used the Diode DMM option and measured a forward voltage drop of 0.24V, and the package is likely SOD 523 given that the length and width are about 1.15mm by 0.75mm, measured with a caliper. Here's a picture of the component (through a microscope):

If anyone knows what this component could be, or has any ideas about how to go about finding a replacement, I'd appreciate the help! Thanks!

Your best bet is to find the current and voltage that this diode needs to withstand, and then choose a suitable replacement. Even if it's not exactly the same type, it'll work as long as it's similar. So... What circuitry is connected to this diode?

Get out a meter and test it for conductivity and in diode mode

What do you mean "melted"? How exactly did you determine that it was broken?

"C" marking in SOD-523 should be a RB521S-30.
However it is difficult to find the manufacturer. This designation seems to be a generic one. But with the orientation of the "C" and the fact that the cathode band is a single one and has a thin width, maybe you can try to isolate possibilities on LCSC by looking one by one pictures. But there are many.
One of them from LCSC website:


That looks promising! There's only two manufacturers on Digi-Key that sell ones that look like this, I'll give them both a shot - thank you!
